# What is the best free option for automatic ftp sync with finder?

Tags: finder, ftp, webserver

I was quite happy when I found out that Finder had native support, but it didn't take long until I realized it was read-only access.

What is the best free option for automatic ftp sync with finder? I am using El Capitan. I'm not interested in very much functionality, just the ability to edit files.

Comment: So, do you want FTP acces? Or do you to be able to sync? Or do you just want the ability to edit files?

Comment: I want FTP access automatically syncing with a finder folder I can edit. Dropbox-style.

Answer (score 1):

### TextWrangler

You can use BareBones' [Text Wranger](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/textwrangleradmin.html). It is a free texteditor with onboard `ftp` capability. TextWrangler is BBEdit's little brother, and BBEdit is *one of the best* text editors. I use this text editor at least since Mac OS 7.6 And, just like BBEdit, TextWrangler does not suck.

[image: Demo image from barebones.com]

Answer (score 0):

FileZilla, but beware of the adware in the installer, as its hosted on SourceForge. [CyberDuck](https://cyberduck.io/appstore), in the App Store, is another good option; both support editing and syncing back to the server.

Comment: Is there a free version of CyberDuck? And can I have an automatically synced finder folder with FileZilla?

Comment: Yes -- on their website, there's a [Download button](https://cyberduck.io) between the Windows download and the Mac App Store link. Sorry, I'd forgotten that the App Store version was for pay. And yes, there's a File > Synchronize option, though I've never used it myself.